# How to have two radio buttons side by side in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, layout

I'm having some trouble arranging my view in Kotlin so that I have two radio buttons to be side by side. I would also like to push 'amountPicker' to the right also. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I just cant seem to figure it out. Many thanks in advance. I have tried this many different ways but I just can't seem to get the result that I am looking for. The areas I am looking at are numberPicker and RadioGroup.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.wit.hikingtrails.activities.HikeActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:elevation="0dip"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarAdd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/hikeName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:autofillHints=""
                    android:hint="@string/hint_hikeName"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="25"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_hikeDescription"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="25"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/chooseImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/button_addImage"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/hikeImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/hikeLocation"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                    android:text="@string/button_location"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hikeSubtitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/donateTitle"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/donateTitle"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/hikeSubtitle"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/difficultyLevel"
                    android:layout_width="328dp"
                    android:layout_height="128dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/Hard"
                        android:layout_width="99dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:text="@string/hard" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/Intermediate"
                        android:layout_width="168dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:text="@string/intermediate" />
                </RadioGroup>

                <NumberPicker
                    android:id="@+id/amountPicker"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="121dp"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/donateSubtitle"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.973"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.333" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="349dp"
                    android:layout_height="14dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/donateButton"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/donateSubtitle"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:indeterminate="false"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.526"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/distance"
                    android:layout_width="267dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/distance" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/difficulty"
                    android:layout_width="265dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/difficulty" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                    android:text="@string/button_addHike"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

[![This is how the view currently looks][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1nTN.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:orientation="horizontal"` on your `RadioGroup` - [it's just a LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup#inherited-xml-attributes).

Your `NumberPicker` has a bunch of `ConstraintLayout` positioning attributes defined, but it's not **inside** a `ConstraintLayout` - its parent is a *`LinearLayout`* (the one inside the `ScrollView`) so none of that stuff will work. You'd have to use attributes that `LinearLayout` supports, like `layout_gravity` to align it to one side, or increasing `margin` or `padding` (or both - align to the edge, use margin to push it away from the edge).

If you actually want to use those `ConstraintLayout` attributes (and you have a couple of things in that layout using them, like the `ProgressBar`) you'll have to swap out your `LinearLayout` for a `ConstraintLayout`. Then you'll have a lot more control over positioning!

Comment: cduff, I would also suggest that you should avoid using fixed layout_width and layout_height values. That can cause problems with different screen sizes and if the font size/value of the text changes. Try to use match_parent or wrap_content. There are other ways as well like setting up constraints and putting height/width as 0dp while using constraint layout.
As suggested by @cactustictacs Constraint layout will help you a lot more with the control over positioning compared to linear layout.
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout